# Trying to INSERT a SEQUENCE number into an INSERT statement but having issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a sequence value that I need to increment in an INSERT statement using SQL Server 2014.  I have a variable that contains the max number + 1 that I'm trying to INSERT into a temp table but that number needs to be incremented for each record being inserted into the TEMP TABLE. After googling this issue I found where I need to create a DYNAMIC SQL statement in order to use the variable value.  However when I do that I get now a conversion error.

Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @id = (SELECT MAX(rowNum)+1 FROM dbo.Focus_Export_Econ_DisadvantagedHHS_Staging_TEST)
SET @sql = 'CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.ID_Sequence
    AS INT
    START WITH ' + @id + 
    'INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE'
EXEC @sql;
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR @sql, T.*
INTO #TEMP_TEST  --DROP TABLE #TEMP_TEST 
FROM (SELECT h.SiteID, st.SchoolName, st.CEPSchool, st.StudentID, st.FName, st.LName, st.Grade, UPPER(LEFT(h.Status,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(h.Status,2,LEN(h.Status))) as Status, 
        (CASE
            WHEN UPPER(h.Status) = 'FREE' THEN '01'
            WHEN UPPER(h.Status) = 'REDUCED' THEN '02'
            WHEN UPPER(h.Status) = 'PAID' THEN '00'
        END) as EconomicDisadvantageCode, 
        (CASE 
            WHEN ltrim(h.AppType) = 'HS Survey' THEN 'HH' 
        END) as ApplicationTypeCode,
        'HouseHold Survey' as ApplicationType,
        st.ResAddr, st.City, st.ZipCode, st.State, st.Phone, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(h.Effective_Date as date), 101) as StatusEffectiveDate, h.End_Date, st.SchoolYear, 
        st.BirthDate, st.AppScanned, st.AppOnline, st.GracePeriodID,
        (CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(h.APPID) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, h.APPID) ELSE NULL 
        END) as ApplicationID 
    FROM #TEMP_HHS_Historical_Records h
    INNER JOIN dbo.Focus_Export_Econ_DisadvantagedHHS_Staging_TEST st
    ON h.CustomerID = st.StudentID) as T;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 384
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.ID_Sequence
        AS INT
        START WITH ' to data type int.
```

Comment: `EXEC (@SQL)` not `EXEC @SQL`. Also, you'll need to do `+ CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),@id) +`  rather than just `+ @id +` as `int` has a higher data precedence they `nvarchar`.

Comment: You can still keep `next value` as u don't have a while loop

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an error on the SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR @sql, T.* line above which states:  INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR '@sql'. Expecting '.', ID or QUOTED_ID. Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to cast the ID to nvarchar, like this:

```
DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @id = (SELECT MAX(rowNum)+1 FROM dbo.Focus_Export_Econ_DisadvantagedHHS_Staging_TEST)
SET @sql = 'CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.ID_Sequence
    AS INT
    START WITH ' + cast(@id as nvarchar(100)) + 
    'INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE'
   exec sp_executesql @sql;

--TO GET THE VALUE INTO @ID
SELECT  @id = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ID_Sequence
```

You just need to create the sequence one time.
The you can iterate and get the @id value.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Jorge, thanks for the help.  However, how do I insert this sequence # into my INSERT statement with the code above?  How will the @sql get incremented for each record that I'm inserting?

Comment: There is another problem, i think you need to use exec sp_executesql @sql; instead of EXEC @sql

Comment: to get the next value of sequence:
`SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.ID_Sequence`

Comment: Edited the answer to show how get @id

Comment: Jorge, thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the dynamic SQL.  You can fix this by doing:

```
SET @sql = 'CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.ID_Sequence
    AS INT
    START WITH ' + cast(@id as varchar(255) + '
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MAXVALUE'
EXEC (@sql);
```

I am not sure if the `create sequence` statement allows parameters, but that would be a better choice than munging the string with the value like this.

Comment: `EXEC @SQL` would give an error `Could not find stored procedure 'CREATE SEQUENCE...'.`. It needs the parentheses I added.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Question.  How do I get it into my SELECT for NEXT VALUE or do I need the NEXT VALUE at all?